# using pgfkeys for drawing TikZ paths

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    first/.style = {
        draw,
        ultra thick,
        red,
    },
    second/.style = {
        draw,
        ultra thin,
        blue,
        >=latex,
        ->
    }
}

\makeatletter

\pgfdeclareshape{symbol}{
  \savedanchor{\southwest}{\pgfpoint{-0.5cm}{-0.5cm}}
  \savedanchor{\northeast}{\pgfpoint{0.5cm}{0.5cm}}
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \anchor{north}{\pgfpoint{0}{0.25cm}}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
  \anchor{south}{\pgfpoint{0}{-0.25cm}}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \anchor{inner east}{\pgfpoint{0.5cm - 0.4pt}{0}}
  \anchor{text}{\pgfpoint{-.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox}{-.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox+.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox}}

  \backgroundpath{
    \pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd, first}

    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.5cm + \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep} }{0.5cm - (0.5 + sqrt(1.25))*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep} }}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.5cm - sqrt(5)*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep} }{0}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-0.5cm + \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep} }{-0.5cm + (0.5 + sqrt(1.25))*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep} }}
    \pgfpathclose

    \pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd, second}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.25cm}{-0.5cm}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.25cm}{0.5cm}}
  }
}


\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (a) at (0,0) [symbol] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

this is what is produced with the above code:

[image]

I expect to be able to configure the appearance of the triangle and the line individually with my two individual TikZ styles. So, I actually would expect the triangle to be ultra thick and red, and the single straight line should be ultra thin, blue and equipped with an arrow.

Why is this not the case, and what shall I change?
I already tried `\pgfusepath{stroke}` with no effect.

Comment: How would that work? You'd need to fill these directives into `\pgfsetlinewidth` etc. If that was not the case, you'd mess up decorations by saying `dashed` before.

Comment: One more thing: you cannot change colors in a path. That is, you'd need to say something like `\pgfusepath{stroke}` before switching to a new color. There are, of course, good reasons, *not* to cut the path to pieces (e.g. if you want to fill the region in between). I really think you should have a look at `pic`s and/or `path picture`, which allow you to do these things.

Comment: Obviously it works, but I don't understand all internal workings yet, that's true. Actually I wanted to use PGF shapes because these are exactly designed for what I am planning to do. I had previously some `path pictures`, but there it is also possible to mess things up with some styles.

Answer (score 1):

TikZ is using PGF to do all its drawing, no surprise here. However, the main two paths a shape has, the [`\backgroundpath`](https://tikz.dev/base-nodes#%5Cbackgroundpath) (background because it will be drawn behind the text) and its [`\foregroundpath`](https://tikz.dev/base-nodes#%5Cforegroundpath) (in front of the text), are supposed to be “used” by the user with [`\pgfnode`](https://tikz.dev/base-nodes#%5Cpgfnode) (every `\pgfnode` is a [`\pgfmultipartnode`](https://tikz.dev/base-nodes#%5Cpgfmultipartnode) with one node part):

```
\pgfnode{<shape>}{<anchor>}{<Text>}{<name of node>}{<do something with me>}
```

The `<do something with me>` part is the same stuff that would happen with a normal path, usually at least

```
\pgfusepath{stroke}
```

to draw the shape's path.

Now, when TikZ constructs a path (everything between `\path` and `;`) apart from moving around the “pen” (`--`, `.. controls …`, …) and transformations it doesn't do much, since keys like `draw` and `fill` just store their actions in another internal macro.

Only when `;` is reached all the real magic is finally happening. The stored options and settings are executed, stuff is sorted out (clip? fill? draw? shade? fade? path picture? double? pre- and postactions?), error messages are invoked and whatever.

So when TikZ finds a `;` it will execute `\tikz@finish`.
And this macro will also be used when TikZ adds a node
because a node's path is supposed to act the same as any other path in PGF/TikZ:

```
 \pgfmultipartnode{<shape>}{<anchor>}{<name of node>}{%
              \pgfutil@tempdima=\pgflinewidth%
              {\begingroup\tikz@finish}%
              \global\pgflinewidth=\pgfutil@tempdima%
            }%
```

It does some juggling around with the linewidth, I'm assuming it restores the linewidth of the path because `\tikz@finish` might globally set it to something else.

Since `\tikz@finish` (remember, it's the `;`) also closes the group that `\path` starts, it needs a `\begingroup`. (The settings are set beforehand but are still valid inside this group that doesn't do anything really.)

---

To cut a long story short, you need to instruct your shape to use the `\tikz@finish`er.

This could be just

```
\backgroundpath{%
  \begingroup
    \tikzset{first}%
    \pgfpathmoveto
      {\pgfpoint{-0.5cm + \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}
                { 0.5cm - (0.5 + sqrt(1.25))*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}%
    \pgfpathlineto
      {\pgfpoint{0.5cm - sqrt(5)*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{0pt}}%
    \pgfpathlineto
      {\pgfpoint{-0.5cm + \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}
                {-0.5cm + (0.5 + sqrt(1.25))*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}%
    \pgfpathclose
  \tikz@finish
  \begingroup
    \tikzset{second}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-0.25cm}{-0.5cm}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.25cm}{0.5cm}}%
  \tikz@finish
}
```

The `\begingroup\tikzset{first}` doesn't need to be at the start of the path unless you want to use transformations and other fancy stuff that actually changes the path. But since you only use `draw`, linewidth and a color, this would do, too:

```
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-0.25cm}{-0.5cm}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.25cm}{0.5cm}}%
\begingroup
  \tikzset{second}%
\tikz@finish
```

(Transformation actually need `\let\tikz@transform\relax` to work but that's a whole other thing.)

So we're actually have three paths: the `first`, the `second` and the empty one that's done by TikZ with its call to `\pgfmultinodepart`.

---

It might be better to move these things to one of the other paths where the shape is supposed to explicitly do something with it (stroke, fill, …) and not use one of the paths the user is supposed to “use”. But this all is dependent on your actual use-case – and who your users will be.

---

That said, a `pic` might be the better option to use but that is also depending on the use-case.

### Code

```
\documentclass[border=1mm, tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  first/.style  = {draw, ultra thick, red},
  second/.style = {draw, ultra thin, blue, >=latex, ->}}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{symbol}{
  \savedanchor{\southwest}{\pgfqpoint{-0.5cm}{-0.5cm}}
  \savedanchor{\northeast}{\pgfqpoint{0.5cm}{0.5cm}}
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \anchor{north}{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0.25cm}}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
  \anchor{south}{\pgfqpoint{pt0}{-0.25cm}}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \anchor{inner east}{\pgfpoint{0.5cm - 0.4pt}{+0pt}}
  \anchor{text}{\pgfpoint{-.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox}{-.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox+.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox}}
  \backgroundpath{%
    \begingroup
      % \let\tikz@transform\relax if you want transformations to work
      \tikzset{first}%
      \pgfpathmoveto
        {\pgfpoint{-0.5cm + \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}
                  { 0.5cm - (0.5 + sqrt(1.25))*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}%
      \pgfpathlineto
        {\pgfpoint{0.5cm - sqrt(5)*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{0pt}}%
      \pgfpathlineto
        {\pgfpoint{-0.5cm + \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}
                  {-0.5cm + (0.5 + sqrt(1.25))*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}%
      \pgfpathclose
    \tikz@finish
    \begingroup
      \tikzset{second}%
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-0.25cm}{-0.5cm}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.25cm}{0.5cm}}%
    \tikz@finish
  }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[nodes=symbol] {
  \node {};         & \node                      [green] {.}; \\
  \node[dashed] {}; & \node[second/.append style={green}]{.}; \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: By the way, the definition of `text` is wrong (can't use `\pgfnodeparttextbox`).